# Ionic delete flat arrow of IonSelect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

How can I remove this arrow of IonSelect on ionic 5 use Reactjs? I customized it and I want to delete it.

[image]

Comment: Can you add what your current code looks like for the component?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    .my-dropdown-toggle::after {
        content: none;
    }
```

Comment: ionic5 don't work
i can change on inline style with shadow dom but i can't change on css
<div class="select-icon" role="presentation" part="icon" style="
    display: none;
"><div class="select-icon-inner"></div></div>